# How does PHP PDO::query actually do?

Tags: php, pdo

Bit of confusion about what PDO::query does. Fully understand the difference between it and a prepare and execute, however it is unclear about if query runs a fetch. According to PHP.net:

> PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object

which is proven by:

```
$s = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM user');
var_dump($s);
```

which outputs:

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=> string(18) "SELECT * FROM user"
}
```

So its clearly giving us a PDOStatement object ready to run fetch or fetchAll on. HOWEVER. Take the following code taken from the PHP.net manual:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
}
```

This indicates that running a PDO::query actually runs a fetch internally and returns a result (which is mentioned in the initial description for the method). However if that is true then a subsequent call to fetch should return the second row, however it does not, you still get the first row.

Does query run a fetch and reset the pointer so a subsequent fetch also returns the first row? if so, is this not unperformant? and why can you loop query and get multiple rows? does it run some kind of coroutine using yield? Additionally, why can you not see the fetched data in the PDOStatement object? Presumerably they are hiding this data using the __set_state and __debugInfo magic methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is irrelevant to what does PHP `PDO::query` actually do. But rather to what `PDOStatement` actually is. And it is [an object that supports a `Traversable` interface](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach), so *it can be iterated over*. And when iterated, it is internally calling `fetch()` consequently.

> it is unclear about if query runs a fetch

PDO::query never runs a fetch. PDOStatement does. In the following line the short syntax is used for brevity.

```
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row)
```

While it can be written as

```
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
foreach ($stmt as $row)
```

as `foreach` is iterating over the result, returned by query, not running query again and again

> why can you not see the fetched data in the `PDOStatement` object?

because there is no such data.

Hope it is all clear now

Comment: There is no coroutine or yield at hand here. With the old (now deprecated) MySQL functions this was actually a bit clearer.

Comment: After MySQL receives (and executes) the SELECT it holds the result set. Each call to `mysql_fetch_row` asks MySQL to push the next item in the result set (like an SQL cursor).

Comment: @MihaiStancu [this resultset is hold rather on PHP side](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd).

Comment: So you see there is not PHP+MySQL coroutine (cross application coroutines?) and there is no `yield` (yield from what? `SELECT LIMIT A.B`?).

Comment: I'd beg to differ (although I'm not sure about this) because I remember having tested this exact issue a while back based on memory consumption.

Comment: thank you very much, this makes sense! not very clear on php.net

Comment: @MikeOram please note that this question is about how PDOStatement works internally. And yes, it is calling mysql_fetch_row to fetch the next result. And so as it's emulating an array, there should be a yield-like routine, isn't it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense -- OK so `mysql_*` buffered queries locally but in the client library while `mysqli_` and `PDO` buffers them locally in PHP.

Comment: @MikeOram pretty much like than save for a "client library" is effectively part of PHP :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense -- there is no need for a yield as long as you retain (internally) where you left off (each call to `mysql_fetch_row` increments the position).

Comment: @MihaiStancu yield is meant in the sense of PHP [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php),

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, I know and that is exactly what I am arguing against -- yield implies a function has not finished executing but exposes data to the external context and blocks until the external context is finished.

Comment: @YourCommonSense as you said the `Iterator` functions `next`, `valid` and `current` are called on each `foreach` loop. When they are called `next` probably increments an internal counter, `valid` checks to see if the result set has a value at that position, `current` executes the `fetch` command.

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is a transparent loop, you're looping over the PDOStatement object and calling next/valid/current on each iteration. Not a generator based loop receiving it's values from inside the `query` function.